# store access_token via @anywhere twitter application

Tags: javascript, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-anywhere

Is there a way to get the right user credentials from the twitter "@Anywhere" JS library so I can store them in a database for later offline use? I want my users to be able to just authenticate once and then I store those credentials (or tokens or whatever) so that when they post a message with my service it gets pushed to their twitter account.

Facebook connect js library made this very easy, I assume it's possible with twitter @anywhere, but I could be wrong, docs don't specify.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible. Twitter Anywhere.js is just for Client side use and the tokens are different that off serverside tokens. Drop anywhere.js and go serverside.